# Decoding JSON error in Flutter, type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'

Tags: json, flutter, mobile

I'm calling an API and it keeps getting back this error `Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'` and even though I've tried almost everything, I can't seem to resolve the issue. The app doesn't break but the I can't display the data since there is no data received. The API call looks like this:

```
Future<HTTPResponse<List<Data>>> getData() async {
  final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  String value = await storage.read(key: 'jwt');
  String email = await storage.read(key: "e");
  final response = await get(
    'EnvConfig.apiEndpint' +
        email,
    headers: {'Authorization': value},
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<Data> somedata= [];
    body.forEach((e) {
      Data data = Data.fromJson(e);
      somedata.add(data);
    });
    return HTTPResponse<List<Data>>(
      true,
      accounts,
      message: 'Request Successful',
      statusCode: response.statusCode,
    );
  } else {
    return HTTPResponse<List<Data>>(
      false,
      null,
      message:
          'Invalid data received from the server! Please try again in a moment.',
      statusCode: response.statusCode,
    );
  }
}
```

I call this method in an `initState` in one of the widgets like this:

```
_getDataList() async {
    var provider = Provider.of<DataStore>(context, listen: false);

    var dataResponse = await getData();
    if (dataResponse .isSuccessful) {
      provider.setDataList(dataResponse.data, notify: false);
    } else {
      provider.mergeDataList(dataResponse.data, notify: false);
    }

    provider.setIsDataListProcessing(false);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _getDataList();
  }
```

The data model:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:core';

class Data {
  final String dateCreated, dateModified, name, email, type;
  final bool active;
  final int accountNumber, accountPriority;

  Data ({
    this.dateCreated,
    this.dateModified,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.type,
    this.active,
    this.accountNumber,
    this.accountPriority,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      dateCreated: json['dateCreated'],
      dateModified: json['dateModified'],
      name: json['name'],
      email: json['email'],
      type: json['type'],
      active: json['active'],
      accountNumber: json['accountNumber'],
      accountPriority: json['accountPriority'],
    );
  }
}
```

And the response body:

```
this is the response body{"statusCode":200,"message":"Success"}
```

I can't seems to understand how to set this JSON decoding like it should be. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What `response.statusCode` you get?

Comment: Hi, this is the status code. `{"statusCode":200,"message":"Success"}`.

Comment: I've tried this exact method with a different API and I get the values back, but with this custom API something is wrong and it seems I can't decode it properly.

Comment: maybe show us `response.body` and your `Data` class ?

Comment: Added both as requested

Comment: well, your response body only contains `statusCode` and `message`,  no `dateCreated`, `dateModified` .. ?

Comment: Nothing. Maybe my endpoint is just off, will update the status after I debug.

Comment: So, I've made it and just hit the correct path of the API endpoint, last night everything was working, went to sleep, again the same error, `type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'`. Bloody hell...

Comment: check the `response.body`.

Comment: So instead of final `int accountNumber, accountPriority;` I have changed it to final `dynamic accountNumber, accountPriority;` and everyhting is working for now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: thanks for the update